# Use of the term 'disappeared' - meaning 'exterminate'

Tags: grammaticality, word-usage

Is it correct to say “...a young man who had been ‘disappeared’.”

I need this to align with a statement used earlier in the text: “Many civilians simply ‘disappeared’ with no trace found afterwards.”

Many thanks in advance for all input.

Comment: *Disappear* can certainly be used as a transitive verb, as in "had been disappeared".

Comment: Particularly in some South American countries, people who are arrested by quasi-government militias and either secretly imprisoned or executed are said to have been "disappeared" (or the Spanish/Portuguese equivalent).  The quote marks around *disappeared* in your above quotation suggest that this meaning is intended.

Comment: @HotLicks exactly. That was the intended meaning.

Comment: I don't know about "correctness" but it loses the effect if you structure the sentence as if it's a drop-in replacement for murdered, even though it basically means the same thing. The whole point is to allude to the tyrants' "official"(falsified) report made to "alleviate worries" or absolve "wrongful allegations"(hide the truth) by quoting *their* words, so the sentence should be structured like how *they'd* report it, which certainly wouldn't be "had been disappeared"  I'd suggest just writing a young man who had "disappeared" and using tonal inflection, possibly with air quotes, in speech.